# "ping myserver-name.local" returning "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: ping, hostname, ubuntu-server, local

I have an ubuntu server in my local network that I can ping using its IP address.

However, following the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/646494/972577), when I try

```
ping myserver-name.local
```

I get

```
Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have also used `avahi-resolve-address` make sure I am using the correct name.

Any idea how I can debug this issue?